# Apple II c repair keyboard and check disk driver error

Tags: apple-ii

I'm new in this forum and I want to say hello to all and sorry my bad English!

I'm trying to repair an Apple II c computer that was stored in my house for many years. When I stored it, like 15 years ago, it works without no problem but few days ago I have reconnected it and I have discovered two big problem:

- First was a strange behaviour of the keyboard: all the special characters like "( ) , ; -_ " and numbers works great but all the other letters don't come on screen (same for the number "5" only): when I press the keyboard button the cursors on screen flickers, so I think something happens... but without letters I can't put any command
- Second problem was that every disc I use, give the message "Check Disk Drive": I have tried many disks, most are Official Apple Discs coming with the computer, other are old games and similar but I have the same result

I have disassemble the computer, make a quick clean from dust, check the keyboard buttons and cable and all appear ok but first problem remains.

For the second problem, I tried to clean the disk reader parts, and also, I have tried to use another disk reader getting it from the external drive (I have also the external driver but I can't use it directly because can't put commands to active it) but the result is the same.

Here you can found other image and videos:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14nbEQOa3n7xhUkG23BAJj1O_ADQ0ZhKy?usp=sharing

How can I do for trying to repair it? I need a new keyboard? Where I can buy it? You think both disk reader are broken or ALL my 5 inches disk are unreadable? Where I can buy a disk that I'm sure it's work to understand if is the disk reader or the 5 inches floppy? Other ideas?

Glad of your help

Comment: Hello to you too! Unfortunately I don’t think this is a very good question as it stands. It would be better if you could post about your different problems with the machine in separate questions. Take a moment to read [the tour](/tour) too; this is a Q&A site where posts are expected to fit a specific format, not a free-form discussion board.